# Detect when my mouse is on 2 rect and choose the action

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I don't know how to detect when my mouse is on 2 rect and choose (if two rect has an action) the action. For example, in Windows, when two windows are one over the other, it's the first window that will be selected. I want to do exactly the same thing.

```
import pygame

class Rectangle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen, rect, x, y, color, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.name = name
        self.screen_str = str(screen)
        self.rect = rect
        self.color = color
        self.x, self.y = x, y

        self.r = pygame.Surface((self.rect[2], self.rect[3]), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        self.rect = self.r.get_rect()
        self.rect.x, self.rect.y = x, y

        self.r.fill(self.color)

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
pygame.display.set_caption("PyStoneTest")
width, height = screen.get_size()
background_default = "image\Settings\Wallpaper\default_1.jpg"

D = {}

D["Rect2"] = Rectangle(screen, (0, 200, width, 70), 0,
                             50, (255, 255, 0), "Rect2")

D["Rect1"] = Rectangle(screen, (0, 100, width-200, 200), 0,
                             100, (255, 0, 255), "Rect1")

Programme = ["Rect1", "Rect2"]

while True:
    background = pygame.image.load(background_default).convert()
    background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (width, height))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        for element in Programme:
            if D[element].rect.collidepoint(x,y) and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                del Programme[Programme.index(D[element].name)]
                Programme.append(D[element].name)
                print(Programme)

    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    for element in Programme:
        screen.blit(D[element].r, D[element].rect)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: How do you determine which rect is the "first"? What's wrong with your current code? How is its output or behavior different from what you expect?

Comment: Are you trying to check whether the mouse is "on" both of them at once? Or either one? Or should the code do something separate for each rectangle? "For example, in Windows, when two windows are one over the other, it's the first window that will be selected." You get that by checking the top window first, and only checking the bottom window if the top window was missed.

Comment: maybe in `for`-loop use `break`when you find first rect to skip other rects

Comment: I think code could be more readable (and maybe it would use little less CPU) if you would first check only `event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`. And after that you can use `even.pos` instead of `x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()`

Comment: it could load background and transform it before `while True`

Comment: code could be simpler if you would keep `Rectangle` directly in `Programme` instead of using `D`

Comment: in your code `element` and `D[element].name` has the same text so you could use `element` instead of `D[element].name` to reduce code. ie. `Programme.remove(element)` and `Programme.append(element)`

Comment: it is not good idea to remove element from list which is iterated

Comment: char \ has special meaning in string - even in file path - so better use \\ or prefix `r` for `raw string`

Answer (score 1):

I cannot help with your code since I cannot understand what you are doing but I can offer my own solution. Since pygame renders thigs that are drawn later on the top, you can change the rendering order of your rectangles by checking which rectangle is being clicked and swapping it with the last rectangle in your list.

Here is an example. The colors in my example change weirdly but that's because I am generating them on the fly just to be able to tell the different between the different rects. You shouldn't have this problem.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
pygame.display.set_caption("PyStoneTest")

rects = []

for i in range(10):
    rects.append(pygame.Rect(i * 25, 100, 30, 30))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    c = 1
    for rect in rects:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (c, 100, 100), rect)
        c += 20

    clicked = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for rect in rects:
        if (rect.collidepoint(x, y) and clicked[0]):
            #swap it
            rects[-1][:], rect[:] = rect[:], rects[-1][:]

        
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first run `for`-loop to check all windows and use last one which collides with mouse.

```py
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            last = None

            for element in Programme:
                if D[element].rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    last = element

            if last:
               Programme.remove(last)
               Programme.append(last)
               print(Programme)
```

Or you would have to check in reverse order - from last to first - and `break` loop on first matching rectangle.

```py
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            last = None

            for element in reversed(Programme):
                if D[element].rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    last = element
                    break

            if last:
               Programme.remove(last)
               Programme.append(last)
               print(Programme)
```

---

Minimal working code with other changes

```py
import pygame

# --- classes ---

class Rectangle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    
    # I skip `x,y` because I have it in `rect`
    def __init__(self, screen, rect, color, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.color = color
        self.name = name

        self.rect  = pygame.Rect(rect)
        self.image = pygame.Surface(self.rect.size, pygame.SRCALPHA)

        self.image.fill(self.color)

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

# --- functions ---

# empty

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()  # it can be useful to center elements on screen - `d[name].rect.center = screen_rect.center`

pygame.display.set_caption("PyStoneTest")

# raw string
background_default = r"image\Settings\Wallpaper\default_1.jpg"

# load and rescale before `while`-loop
background = pygame.image.load(background_default).convert()
background = pygame.transform.scale(background, screen_rect.size)

d = {}  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variable 

d["Rect2"] = Rectangle(screen, (0, 0, screen_rect.width-100, 70), (255, 255, 0), "Rect2")
d["Rect2"].rect.center = screen_rect.center

d["Rect1"] = Rectangle(screen, (0, 0, 70, screen_rect.height-100), (255, 0, 255), "Rect1")
d["Rect1"].rect.center = screen_rect.center

programme = ["Rect1", "Rect2"]  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variable

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()  # to skip rest of while-loop
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            selected = None
            for name in programme:
                if d[name].rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    selected = name
            if selected and selected != programme[-1]:
               programme.remove(selected)
               programme.append(selected)
               print('after replace:', programme)

    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

    for name in programme:
        d[name].draw()

    pygame.display.update()
```